# For loops with user input (probably easy: just not computer-literate)

Tags: java, for-loop

Thank you, Ascalonian. I was able to get the code to print the number desired, but they're stacking on top of one another rather than printing the boxes out side by side? If I use System.out.print I get this

```
+------+|      ||      |------+|      ||      |+------+
```

If I use System.out.println I get this

```
+------+
|      |
|      |
------+
|      |
|      |
+------+
```

Suggestions?

So here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

Enter number of boxes: 3

```
+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |
|      |      |      |
+------+------+------+
```

Let me start of by saying I'm taking a required class for my job at the moment and am in no way trying to work with this stuff. I just need to survive this class. That being said...

This is the code I have so far....

```
public static void boxes( ) {     
    System.out.print("Enter the number of boxes: ");
    int numBoxes = CONSOLE.nextInt( );

    System.out.print("+");
    for (int i= 1; i<numBoxes; i++) {
        System.out.print("------+");
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do (and not sure why it's not working though I'm sure it's simple as all get out) is to get second system.out with the dashes and plus to be printed the specified user number of times. I haven't even begun on how to do the lines that make up the sides (what I guess will be another for loop). Any help would be greatly appreciated and is definitely whole-heartedly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Problem is no matter what number is entered I only get one line to print not the amount of lines the user indicates :(

Comment: You've got the top line, and do the same thing for the bottom line. Now you just need to do 2 other for-loops to print the bars with the same idea you already have. So you print out the bar, then in the for-loop print out the same number of empty spaces as there were dashes and print the bar again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point. Good luck with your course.

```
    int numBoxes = 3;
    System.out.print("+");
    for (int i = 0; i<numBoxes; i++) {
        System.out.print("------+");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("|");
    for (int i = 0; i<numBoxes; i++) {
        System.out.print("      |");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("|");
    for (int i = 0; i<numBoxes; i++) {
        System.out.print("      |");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("+");
    for (int i = 0; i<numBoxes; i++) {
        System.out.print("------+");
    }
```

Comment: and Ascalonian Thank you both for taking the time. I really appreciate it. You ever need help in neurosciences hit me up :)